# AngularJs element on change event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is the following code:

```
  handleFileSelect = (evt) ->
    console.log(1)
    file = evt.currentTarget.files[0]
    reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = (evt) ->
      $scope.$apply ($scope) ->
        $scope.myImage = evt.target.result
      reader.readAsDataURL(file)
  angular.element(document.querySelector('#fileInput')).on('change', handleFileSelect)
```

And HTML:

```
<div class="form-group ng-scope">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="image">Image:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="cropFile">
      <input id="fileInput" type="file">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to get '1' in console after I change some file in `#fileInput`. But when I choose file I get nothing. How can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: `<input id="fileInput" type="file" ng-change="handleFileSelect()" />`

Comment: I add it, add move handleFileSelect to $scope, but it doesn't work..

Comment: any luck with this, having similar problem??

Answer (score 5):

Do this by making a directive.

I have created a directive name **upload**

**HTML PART**

```
<div><input style="margin: 0 auto;" type="file" id="fileInput" upload></div>
```

**JS for Directive**

```
myapp.directive('upload', function($rootScope) {
return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.on("change" ,function(evt) {
            var file = evt.currentTarget.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(evt) {
                scope.$apply(function($scope) {
                    $rootScope.myImage = evt.target.result;
                    console.log($rootScope.myImage);
                });
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        });
    }
  };
});
```